# Pandas: How to Read Excel with merged cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read one excel file with pandas.
It consists of merged cells.
I am expecting to get the output as shown in the below screenshot

Possible Answer   : To use fillna() method
Problem with that : 1. As shown in Screenshot there are inconsistent blank rows in between two
merged cells
2. the Second column also has random blank cells
[InPut file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNgkX.png)

[Expected Output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9XjQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=None).dropna(how='all')
df[0] = df[0].ffill()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         0    1
2    Large    A
3    Large    B
5    Large    C
6    Large    D
8   Medium    E
9   Medium    F
10  Medium    G
11  Medium    H
14   Small  NaN
15   Small    I
16   Small    J
17   Small    K
```

Comment: @Satish. Did you have time to test the code?